# Complex Coherence with SNAP or SarScape

Tags: remote-sensing, insar, sentinel-snap

is it possible to estimate the **complex** coherence between two RADARSAT-2 SLC images with SNAP or SarScape? If I try to estimate the Coherence I get only float data but I need it in a complex form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was cross-posted to the ESA forum: http://forum.step.esa.int/t/complex-coherence-with-snap/2442

At the time it was asked this was not possible and the OP used a Python script to calculate it himself.